# angucomplete-alt: getting value of text when it doesn't match

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

Angucomplete-alt works great for me when trying to force the user into a pre-defined selection among objects.

But if I don't want to force the user to one of those objects, if instead I want the user to be able to enter free text and only have the completions as *suggestions*, how then do I access the text of the input field?

For example I have a hidden field that marshals the string value of the Angucomplete-alt field for submission to the backend DB. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dance[start_type]"
       ng-value="IS_THERE_A_SELECTION ? selectedStartType.originalObject.name : JUST_TELL_ME_THE_STRING_THEY_TYPED"/>
```

What expressions should I put for IS_THERE_A_SELECTION and JUST_TELL_ME_THE_STRING_THEY_TYPED?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Been banging my head against this one too.  Finally just solved it but requires altering some of the angucomplete-alt source.  It also uses ng-model for two way data binding.

All you need to do is add

```
searchStr: '=ngModel',
```

to the directive's internal scope.  Add right after

```
focusIn:"&"
```

You now have access to ng-model in in the angucomplete-alt directive.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I've been searching all over the web for this and it only appears to have been solved here. Disappointing it was never accepted!

Comment: Glad I could help. I opened a pull request for angucomplete-alt, still waiting though...

Comment: Excellent answer. They should merge your pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it clear, the only value which you want, is inputted string.

```
$scope.localSearch = function(str) {
    ...
}
```

readme.md mentioned this method in the demo, and this parameter **"str"** is exactly the inputted string in the textbox. Feel free to set this value to any variable.